# "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist" when running phpunit with code coverage report for Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm trying to add the code-coverage report feature for phpunit in Laravel 6 by following the tutorial https://coderwall.com/p/mxtqiw/add-code-coverage-report-to-laravel-project

after adding the logging node  on the `phpunit.php` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    ...
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./report" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

and running the command

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

(or just simply running `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html reports/` Without adding the logging node in phpunit.php)

it shows

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(803): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')
#1 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')
#2 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array)
#3 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(120): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array)
#4 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/app/Admin/bootstrap.php(47): app('view')
#5 /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/phpunit/php-code-cov in /mnt/d/User/Projects/63.Roundrobinapp/proj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 805
```

I've tried using the solutions from similar problems such as installing xdebug, using `composer dump-autoload -o`, and cleaning the folder `bootstrap/cache/*.php`, but still no avail.

Any help or just simply give me the right way to add code coverage in Laravel would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like either like a bug-report for laravel to me or a laravel container configuration problem - maybe laravel could provide better error messages on container configuration issues but that's a common issue across anything container/DI related components (sadly). -- check that bootstrapping the tests is complete for the application under test.

Comment: Alright, I've moved this to the Laravel forum instead.

Comment: Leave a link here in comments so it's easy to keep track for future visitors.